# How to dynamically remove a decorator from a function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-decorators

I'd like to activate or deactivate a "cache" in some class method during execution.

I found a way to activate it with something like that:

```
(...)
setattr(self, "_greedy_function", my_cache_decorator(self._cache)(getattr(self, "_greedy_function")))
(...)
```

where `self._cache` is a cache object of my own that stores the results of `self._greedy_function`.

It's working fine but now what if I want to deactivate the cache and "undecorate" `_greedy_function`?

I see a possible solution, storing the reference of `_greedy_function` before decorating it but maybe there is a way to retrieve it from the decorated function and that would be better.

As requested, here are the decorator and the cache object I'm using to cache results of my class functions:

```
import logging
from collections import OrderedDict, namedtuple
from functools import wraps

logging.basicConfig(
    level=logging.WARNING,
    format='%(asctime)s %(name)s %(levelname)s %(message)s'
)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

CacheInfo = namedtuple("CacheInfo", "hits misses maxsize currsize")

def lru_cache(cache):
    """
    A replacement for functools.lru_cache() build on a custom LRU Class.
    It can cache class methods.
    """
    def decorator(func):
        logger.debug("assigning cache %r to function %s" % (cache, func.__name__))
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped_func(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                ret = cache[args]
                logger.debug("cached value returned for function %s" % func.__name__)
                return ret
            except KeyError:
                try:
                    ret = func(*args, **kwargs)
                except:
                    raise
                else:
                    logger.debug("cache updated for function %s" % func.__name__)
                    cache[args] = ret
                    return ret
        return wrapped_func
    return decorator

class LRU(OrderedDict):
    """
    Custom implementation of a LRU cache, build on top of an Ordered dict.
    """
    __slots__ = "_hits", "_misses", "_maxsize"

    def __new__(cls, maxsize=128):
        if maxsize is None:
            return None
        return super().__new__(cls, maxsize=maxsize)

    def __init__(self, maxsize=128, *args, **kwargs):
        self.maxsize = maxsize
        self._hits = 0
        self._misses = 0
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        try:
            value = super().__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            self._misses += 1
            raise
        else:
            self.move_to_end(key)
            self._hits += 1
            return value

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        super().__setitem__(key, value)
        if len(self) > self._maxsize:
            oldest, = next(iter(self))
            del self[oldest]

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        try:
            super().__delitem__((key,))
        except KeyError:
            pass

    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s object at %s: %s>" % (self.__class__.__name__, hex(id(self)), self.cache_info())

    def cache_info(self):
        return CacheInfo(self._hits, self._misses, self._maxsize, len(self))

    def clear(self):
        super().clear()
        self._hits, self._misses = 0, 0

    @property
    def maxsize(self):
        return self._maxsize

    @maxsize.setter
    def maxsize(self, maxsize):
        if not isinstance(maxsize, int):
            raise TypeError
        elif maxsize < 2:
            raise ValueError
        elif maxsize & (maxsize - 1) != 0:
            logger.warning("LRU feature performs best when maxsize is a power-of-two, maybe.")
        while maxsize < len(self):
            oldest, = next(iter(self))
            print(oldest)
            del self[oldest]
        self._maxsize = maxsize
```

**Edit:** I've updated my code using the __wrapped__ attribute suggested in comments and it's working fine! The whole thing is here: https://gist.github.com/fbparis/b3ddd5673b603b42c880974b23db7cda (kik.set_cache() method...)

Comment: "maybe there is a way to retrieve it from the decorated function" Maybe, unfortunately we don't know what the decorated function is.

Comment: @Goyo The "decorated function" is `_greedy_function` which is generated by `my_cache_decorator`. So the question is already clearly defined. Although, it would be better if the PO can provide more context of the decorator.

Comment: How is `lru_cache` used in your class? I don't see any reference to it after declaration.

Comment: Is the line `setattr(self, "_greedy_function",...)` inside a [classmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod)? If so, the argument name `self` should be renamed to `cls`. Otherwise, you're confusing the reader.

Comment: @gdlmx no it's in a "normal" method, and the dynamic decorating works just fine :)

Comment: Usually wrappers provide the `__wrapped__` attribute for this purpose.  That said, I’d recommend using/making a wrapper that *provides* a switch, rather than removing and reinstating the wrapper.

Comment: @DavisHerring that's exactly what I was asking, you should answer the question so that I can validate your answer. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @fbparis: Which approach would you like as an answer?

Comment: @DavisHerring That's your answer so you decide, I thought about implementing a "switch" in the decorator but I prefer removing or adding the wrapper rather than calling it for nothing, that's why personally I decided to use the \__wrapped__ attribute...

Comment: There’s no reason to use `setattr`/`getattr` with an identifier as a string literal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modern versions of `functools.wraps` install the original function as an **attribute `__wrapped__`** on the wrappers they create.  (One could search through `__closure__` on the nested functions typically used for the purpose, but other types could be used as well.)  It’s reasonable to expect whatever wrapper to follow this convention.

An alternative is to have a **permanent** wrapper that can be controlled by a **flag**, so that it can be enabled and disabled without removing and reinstating it.  This has the advantage that the wrapper can **keep its state** (here, the cached values).  The flag can be a separate variable (*e.g.*, another attribute on an object bearing the wrapped function, if any) or can be an attribute on the wrapper itself.

Answer (score 4):

You have made things too complicated. The decorator can be simply removed by `del self._greedy_function`. There's no need for a `__wrapped__` attribute.

Here is a minimal implementation of the `set_cache` and `unset_cache` methods:

```
class LRU(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, maxsize=128, *args, **kwargs):
        # ...
        self._cache = dict()
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _greedy_function(self):
        time.sleep(1)
        return time.time()

    def set_cache(self):
        self._greedy_function = lru_cache(self._cache)(getattr(self, "_greedy_function"))

    def unset_cache(self):
        del self._greedy_function
```

Using your decorator `lru_cache`, here are the results

```
o = LRU()
o.set_cache()
print('First call', o._greedy_function())
print('Second call',o._greedy_function()) # Here it prints out the cached value
o.unset_cache()
print('Third call', o._greedy_function()) # The cache is not used
```

Outputs

```
First call 1552966668.735025
Second call 1552966668.735025
Third call 1552966669.7354007
```

Comment: That’s certainly a clean approach when the function in question is a method.

Comment: You put the _cache and _greedy function in the LRU Class but my LRU class is not intended for this, the stuff I want to cache is in other classes, that's why it's complicated... But maybe you're right so I'll review my code first...

Comment: @fbparis Sorry that I didn't read through your 976 lines of codes in your Github-gist. I just took a look in your `kik._set_cache(...)`, which sets decorator for other methods of `kik`. My technique should work in that scenario, because the cache content is basically irrelevant. It can be located anywhere and set to anything.

Comment: @gdlmx Thanks for your answer anyway, I think next time I'll go your way (the 976 lines of unreadable code I've posted are only to provide the context but I didn't expect people to read it :D)

Comment: The common use case is a decorator being used `@decorator` before a function name. You don't actually show how to remove that. This would be really helpful!